# Undefined method 'count' when using '.map' in Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm using Watir to load all apps in a directory with infinite scroll and count them:

```
grid = browser.divs(class: 'rows')[1]
app_urls = grid.map { |app| app.a(class: 'element Link clickable-element').href }
app_urls.count
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
in `method_missing': undefined method `count' for #<Watir::Map: located: false; {:class=>"rows", :tag_name=>"div", :index=>1} --> {:tag_name=>"map"}> (NoMethodError)
```

Why can't I use `.map` in this case and how should I count the number of apps instead?

Answer (score 0):

`grid` is a single `Watr::Div` element. This means that `#map` is actually the method for looking for a `map` element rather than the Enumerable one.

Assuming you're wanting to iterate over the `div`s with class "row", then it should be:

```
grid = browser.divs(class: 'rows')
```

Comment: Actually, there are 2 divs with the class 'rows', that's why the [1] as I need the second one. But your answer helped me solve this issue anyway as I focused on the 'app_urls' instead of the 'grid' variable which contained the problem. Thanks!